# How can I sync events from yahoo/google calendar with MySql? - in PHP for a web app

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, calendar, yahoo

I want to make a web app that will show some data from a MySQL database, and I need it to be able to connect to Yahoo/Google calendars from each user, so the user will add his calendar when he registers. Is that possible?

Comment: Google calendar offers to obtain a URL that contains dates of a calendar. Let the user paste that URL on your website and parse the contents. Done.

Comment: I'll try to make an cronjob on it , the mysql has to update on it's own when the users adds a new event on his calendar

Comment: I didn't say anything about WHEN to parse the URL. :)

Answer (score 2):

Google Calendar allows Web application developers to access user-generated content and event information through its REST-based Developer API. PHP's SimpleXML extension and Zend's GData Library are ideal for processing the XML feeds generated by this API and using them to build customized PHP applications. This article introduces the Google Calendar Data API, demonstrates how you can use it to browse user-generated calendars; add and update calendar events; and perform keyword searches.

Here is the article tutorial for that go to this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/) and learn how to do that. I think that will help you.

Comment: This link is dead. Could you improve your answer please? Thanks